# Angular use image url in scss not working

Tags: angular, image, assets

I have an angular library that contains assets and a scss theme with in the call to an image

```
  background-image: url(assets/img/bg-resize.png);
```

My problem is that this way of doing things works in an Angular 9 project but not in an Angular 10 project.
I would have liked a solution that works in both Angular 9 and Angular 10

Comment: What is not working? Do you get 404 for your assets or something else?

Comment: Quand je build l'application cela ne fonctionne pas

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 background-image: url('../assets/img/bg-resize.png');
```

It's for **app.component.scss**. You many need to include **"../"** based on your folder structure.

I think this will help you...

Comment: This solution works in Angular 10 but not in Angular 9. However, my css is in a lib that is vowed to be used in Angular 9 and in Angular 10 : Can't resolve '../../assets/img/bg-resize.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
  background-image: url('/assets/img/bg-resize.png');
```

Comment: This solution seems to work but when I click on the link of the image it does not find it

Comment: I'm using this with Angular 10 it displays images also I'm able find the source image via link like : http://localhost:5200/assets/img/bg-resize.png